# How to load an Entity from another Bundle on Symfony2

Tags: php, oop, entity, symfony, bundle

Let's say I have two Bundles :

1. `Compagny\InterfaceBundle`
2. `Compagny\UserBundle`

How can I load an Entity of UserBundle in the controller of InterfaceBundle ?

The `Controller` of my `Compagny/InterfaceBundle` :

```
<?php
// src/Compagny/InterfaceBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace Compagny\InterfaceBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Compagny\UserBundle\Entity; // I believed this line will do the trick, but it doesn't

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $user = new User();
    }
}
```

The `Entity` of my `Compagny/UserBundle` :

```
<?php

namespace Compagny\UserBundle\Entity

class User {
 public $name;
 public function setName($name) {
  // ...
 }
 public function getName() {
  // ...
 } 
}
```

(Let's says for this example that the User class doesn't use Doctrine2, because it doesn't need to connect to the database).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<?php
// src/Compagny/InterfaceBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace Compagny\InterfaceBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Compagny\UserBundle\Entity\User; // It's not a trick, it's PHP 5.3 namespacing!

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $user = new User();
    }
}
```

You can of course, you are just using a class from another namespace. The fact that it is an entity is not important at all! You can of course query the entity manager for that entity as well.